# Affine transformation: rotate a plane parallel to another plane

Tags: mathematics, rotation

I am writing a function that extrudes a 2D shape along a 3D spline, as found in 3D modeling software.

I need a way of translating a set of points P so that they all lie in a new plane L (preserving distances between points).

- P is all points where Z = 0;
- L is defined by (0,0,0), with the normal vector N.

I am using Processing, it has common matrix and vector functionality (but no quaternions) 
A conceptual or pseudo-code answer is OK.

Comment: I just discovered a library for processing that includes quaternion rotation and euler angles.  I've been trying to do something similar but looks like I should use this library. https://github.com/remixlab/proscene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a way of translating a set of points P

I suppose you mean *rotating* here?

Let `Z = (0,0,1)`. If `cross(N,Z)` has length 0, it means that all your points already lie in the desired plane. Otherwise we can build a basis of the target plane:

- `U = normalize(cross(N,Z))`
- `V = cross(N,U)`

Now to transform a point `P = (x,y,0)` so that it lies in your target plane, simply do this:

```
P2 = x * U + y * V
```

Comment: does the line V = cross(N,V) contain a typo?  V is not defined?  Did you mean U?

Comment: oops, yes, it should be U! Fixed.