# Unintended twisting of geometry while generating a mesh?

Tags: mathematics, rotation

I am creating a real time animation of tori (toruses), and I've run into a problem where at certain angles of my tori, the geometry is twisting up where it should remain straight.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/vFIWb9F.gif) is an animated gif of the animation. (sorry I can't embed this)

If you look closely you can see small twists appearing and disappearing in the geometry. Every frame, I am updating the 3D spline which is the guide for the torus, and at certain angles, the mesh gets distorted/twisted.

I've used two different approaches to generate the meshes seen here, one uses the algorithm found [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93983/affine-transformation-rotate-a-plane-parallel-to-another-plane), in an earlier question of mine, and the other, I used a third party quaternion library.  Both approaches produced different, but similar twisting effects.

I'm hoping there is a conceptual idea about 3D rotations I'm missing, as opposed to a small bug in my code, which would take too much of your time to lay out here.

Comment: It looks like you are assuming one vector always will be constant. in particular the up vector. ( 0, 1, 0 ) when your cross that with something that is similar etc where Y = 0,1,0 and Z = 0,1,0. if you cross them you can get effects that are very similar

Comment: 2 quaternions can represent the same rotation (when one is -1*the other), it's possible that you are trying to interpolate across that gap

Comment: Thank you guys.  Tordin, assuming that's the problem, how would I vary the up vector so that doesn't produce this effect?